# How can i install VB.NET in UBUNTU 10.10

Tags: vb.net

hi guys i am the student. and i want to install vb.net 2008 or any version in UBUNTU 10.10
please reply me.......

Comment: I would really consider running dual boot on your machine and having a copy of vb.net instead of running it on Wine o VirtualBox, its really going to be less trouble in the end.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org)
2. Create a new Windows virtual machine
3. Install a Windows guest OS on the new VM
4. Install Visual Studio on the Windows guest VM

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)? It should run fine on Ubuntu without needing to use virtual machines. It might depend a bit on what you want to develop though (for instance, I don't know to what extent it supports stuff like WCF or Workflow Foundation).